# Partitioning Method With Data Entry

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, partitioning

Is there a method that allows the data entered with PostgreSQL, for example, according to time, if the time entered is in a range, that partitioning is made and the entered data is written to the newly opened section?

Imagine a fully automated partitioning structure, data is entered, if there is no compatible partitioned table, a table is created and the data is written to that table.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Yes, it's called an index. What is your end goal that you think you need partitioning?